# How to write a suitable nginx log regular expression

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

$request is an attribute of **log_format**, which format is similar to this：

```
GET /stocks?pattern=1a2b3c&isauto=1&associate=0&userid=4d5e6f&pl=g&isrealcode=1 HTTP/1.1
```

or like this：

```
GET /stocks?pattern=1a2b3c&field=5 HTTP/1.1
```

I want to write a regular expression to intercept the middle string and change its format to the following form：

```
pattern=1a2b3c&...=...&...=... => pattern:1a2b3c,...:...,...:...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression to extract the middle string：

```
    if ($request ~* "GET /stocks\?(.*) HTTP/1.1$"){
        set $custom $1;
    }
```

The extracted string looks like this：

```
pattern=1a2b3c&field=5&...=...
```

How do I replace these symbols：

```
'=' => ':' '$'=>','
```